# Optimizing MySQL update query with two tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 14 million rows and 20 columns in a table named weather and 1900 rows and 15 columns in a table named incident on MySQL server. I am trying to set the active column in weather to 1 where the weather date column is between the start and end date column of the incident table and where the weather location column is equal to the incident location column. I have the following query and I am not sure if it is the most efficient way to do it. It currently has been running for an hour on AWS RDS db.m5.4xlarge (16 vCPU and 64 GB RAM). It is only using 8% CPU according to the AWS Console.

```
UPDATE dev.weather, dev.incident
SET weather.active = 1
WHERE weather.location = incident.location AND weather.DATE BETWEEN dev.incident.start_date AND dev.incident.end_date
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: create index at start date and end date. Use subquery for retrieving small data set and then update

Comment: Provide relevant CREATE TABLE for both tables (all columns used in the query and all indices which includes such columns must be shown). Provide execution plan for your query. PS. Do not use comma-style JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

By the time we come up with a satisfactory solution, your query will be finished.  But here are some thoughts on it.

- `UPDATE`, especially if lots of rows are modified, is very time-consuming.  (This is because of the need to save old rows in case of rollback.)
- Without the indexes, I cannot advise on things completely.
- This is a one-time query, correct?  Future "incidents" will do the update as the incident is stored, correct?  That will probably run reasonably fast.
- Given that you have a way to update for a single incident, use that as the basis for doing the initial `UPDATE` (the one you are asking about now).  That is, write a special, one-time, program to run through the 1900 incidents, performing the necessary Update.  (Advantage:  only one Update need ever be written.)
- Be sure to `COMMIT` after each Update.  (Or run with `autocommit=ON`.)  Else the 1900 updates will be a big burden on the system, perhaps worse than the single-Update that started this discussion.